# Do goroutines and light-weight Java threads mean we never need use thread pools and async code again?

Tags: java, go

I'm trying to wrap my mind around what Goroutines (in Golang) and light-weight threads (in Java 19+) (and perhaps in other languages) mean for programming.

For years, we've been trying to write this extremely unreadable, lambda-function-heavy code in a variety of languages that basically sets up a chain of callbacks, to be invoked asynchronously once I/O is complete or a thread pool has gotten around to working on it. All because thread creation has been an expensive operation and one can't really run a gazillion of OS threads at the same time. In my view, this has always been a very ugly workaround.

I have no first-hand experience with either Goroutines or light-weight threads in Java yet, but it appears to me that we can simply go back to writing straightforward code because these kinds of threads are so cheap.

Is that correct? What would be the downsides of going all-in on those light-weight threads?

Comment: Just because [Java SE 19](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/19/) added [virtual threads (Project Loom)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425) as a preview feature doesn't guarantee it will be added permanently. But the chances are very good in the next year or two.

Comment: As a partial answer, the merits of async (and callbacks) vs. lightweight threads is discussed in both the [virtual threads feature write-up](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425) and the old JavaScript-oriented article ["What color is your function?"](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/).

Comment: And a bunch of Project Loom slideshows: [2018-06](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/JVMLS2018.pdf), [2019-02](https://www.jfokus.se/jfokus19-preso/Project-Loom--One-Year-In.pdf), [2019-05](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/ec-public/materials/2019-05-15/Loom_Overview_May2019.pdf), [2020-11](https://assets.ctfassets.net/oxjq45e8ilak/1d7dQHTHTZyQENr3n1mWYS/0bac7edbcdabdb0703253d510f460bb5/Alan_Bateman_Project_loom_Modern_scalable_concurrency_for_the_Java_platform_2020_11_27_11_44_21.pdf).

Comment: I guess I should not have posted this over the long weekend. But perhaps everybody has the same question and no answer, or has not pondered it yet.

Comment: @Nayuki "Status: Integrated. Fix Version/s: 21". So it is up to delivery in the next LTS in ~September this year, 4-5 months to go.

Answer (score 1):

The downside is cooperative multitasking. That means design mistakes in a virtual thread logic of code could lead to pinning a real thread and leaking them. And it is not the best approach to have computation intensive logic in such threads.

In other words, virtual threads are not multithreaded code in fact, but for asynchronous. However, they still use familiar patterns and approaches which are classical for real threads.

Comment: Can you provide rationale for the assertion "not the best approach to have computation intensive logic in such threads".

Comment: @JohannesErnst I mean if you have a tight loop which does not do any blocking operations, i.e. it does not **cooperate**, the virtual thread will be sticking for a long time to the real thread, so other virtual threads will be waiting in a queue for a chance to get scheduled. In other words, virtual threads should be friendly and cooperate with others. This is opposite of pre-emptive multithreading when threads are allocated time quanta and always rescheduled no matter what they are doing.

Comment: So the only thing you need to do is call yield() every iteration, or so (I assume the have an API for that). Seems doable :-)

Comment: @JohannesErnst However, calling `yield` is not free, it has a performance impact. Hence, not a silver bullet, again.

Comment: @JohannesErnst Oh, and also a long running code could be in an another library which is not under your control, and you may not able to put the `yield` into it.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual threads design idea is to be the best of both worlds. Performance of async callbacks and readability of synchronous blocking code. As Kan mentioned, the only downside to virtual threads is if you pin them by using *synchronized* and then do an IO operation or similar in the synchronized block. Or if you want to do parallel computations, then just regular threads.

And still, this does not mean that you can not do a calculation in a virtual thread. On the contrary. Just use it as a regular old thread, and IF you need high performance parallel computation, then you will need to check if platform threads are better.

But in the context of a web server for example, they are one of the greatest features in the popular languages. Just because, you can do this in spring and make your whole application async without changing anything else, and all existing code becomes async. Also, no async and non async functions. No `Future<String>` and so on. Very elegant, if I may add.

```
@Bean(TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.APPLICATION_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)
public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
  return new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
}

@Bean
public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?> protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
  return protocolHandler -> {
    protocolHandler.setExecutor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
  };
}
```

And even if a virtual thread does computation, well that just means that the Platform thread is just busy, which is our goal, there is no waste there. Just the CPU being utilized far better.

This means that the creators of java intend us to use them without worries about doing computations, as mentioned numerous times in videos by Brian Goetz and others.